# how to share commonly used jquery functions without polluting global namespace?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

Let's say I have these files: a.js b.js c.js which each one is defined like this:

```
(function(){
     function afunction() {
     }

     function yetanotherfunction() {
     }
... ...
})();
```

I also have a file named common.js, which contains functions that can be shared by multiples:

```
function commonFunction() {
}

function yetAnotherCommonFunction() {
}
```

I would like to put commonFunction, yetAnotherCommonFunction inside scope. ie:

```
(function() {
... //commonFunction, yetAnotherCommonFunction goes here
})();
```

however if I do so, I won't be able to call the common functions from a/b/c.js scope. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Create a common object for namespace, and get rid of the IIFE's unless you really do need them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Namespaces:

```
var Common = (function () {
    var Common = {};

    Common.commonFunction = function() {
    }

    return Common;
}())

Common.commonFunction() // do something from anywhere
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a namespace for each script. A simple script to do this would be to have a namespace script like this :

```
var ns = function (namespace, callback) {
   var nssplit = namespace.split('.'), x, curObj = window, curPos = null, lasObj;

   for (x = 0 ; x < nssplit.length ; x++) {
      curPos = nssplit[x];      
      if (curObj[curPos] === undefined) {
         curObj[curPos] = {};
      }
      lasObj = curObj;
      curObj = curObj[curPos];
   }
   lasObj[curPos] = callback;
};

ns('local.test', function() {
   document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "test";
});

local.test();
```

You can see it in action here http://jsfiddle.net/Nemesis02/Qtq8Q/